# Given that the set of the real roots of the equation $P(f(x))=0$ has exactly $3n−1$ elements, prove that $P(-1)\cdot P'(\frac{1}{e}) \ne 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Sorry for the title, I just can't figure another way to title this post in less than 150 characters, here is the full sentence:

Let $f: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R ,f(x)=\frac{|\ln x|}{x}$.
 $P\in \mathbb R[X]$ is a polynomial with degree of $n, n \geq 2$
Given that the set of the real roots of the equation $P(f(x))=0$ has exactly $3n-1$ elements, prove that $P(-1) \cdot P'(\frac{1}{e}) \ne 0$.

I just have absolutely no clue where to start. I would greatly appreciate any kind of help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch $x$ for $\frac1x$ so that $g(x)=f(\frac1x)=x|\ln x|$. Then still $P(g(x))$ has $3n-1$ real roots in $(0,\infty)$.

$g(x)$ has roots at $x=0$ (in the limit) and $x=1$ with the maximum in $(0,1)$ at $x=e^{-1}$, $g(e^{-1})=e^{-1}$. $g$ is increasing for $x>1$. Thus for $P\circ g$ to have $3n-1$ real roots, $P$ itself must have $n$ roots in $(0,e^{-1}]$.

If $e^{-1}$ were not a root, the composition would have $3n$ roots. Thus $P(e^{-1})=0$ and this root, as are all roots indeed, is simple, $P'(e^{-1})\ne 0$. As all roots of $P$ are positive, all function values for negative arguments are non-zero.